# How to update my comments on rails? ERROR: undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I dont get to update my comments on rails.
I am trying to update one comment of one post.
I can generate the form and retrieve the data to inputs. But when I click on submit, shows an error.

The post update works perfectly.
But the comment update dont.

```
Ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p384 (2014-01-12) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Rails -v: Rails 4.2.5.1
```

**My Routes**

```
/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
/posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
/posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
/posts(.:format)                            posts#index
/posts(.:format)                            posts#create
/posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
/posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
/posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
/posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
/posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
/posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
/                                           posts#index
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        if @comment.update(params['post'].permit(:name, :body) )
            redirect_to @post
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @comment, :url => { :action => "update" } do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Model: comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**And the error**

```
undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #18):
16 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
17 @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
18 if @comment.update(params['post'].permit(:name, :body) )
19     redirect_to @post
20 else
21     render 'edit'
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to call permit on `params[:comment]`

```
def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update(params['comment'].permit(:name, :body) )
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Few other things:

- You need to call `update_attributes` on `@comment`, not update
- It is a good practice to find the comment through `@post`, instead of directly loading

`@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])`

Comment: It Works!!! Many Thanks!!! I changed: `if @comment.update(params['post'].permit(:name, :body) )`
TO `if @comment.update(params['comment'].permit(:name, :body) )`. And I followed your advice and changed to: `@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])`. But I did not understand this: _You need to call update_attributes on @comment, not update_ . Can you explain me?

Comment: @user2646969 I always used `update_attributes` while updating an active record object. I don't remember the existence of `update`. Read more about   [update_attributes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L270)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! @Dharam